# Ways to implement booking schedule calendar divided my days and hours on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget

Currently I'm developing a simple site on ASP.NET Core MVC for massage booking which I'll defend at my university. To be honest I'm not sure how to implement a booking schedule calendar functionality where a user can book an hour for a massage therapy.

I might use this bootstrap calendar -> https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/schedule-table#preview

I'm open to any ideas on how to implement this functionality! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @VasilStoyanov, did you want to know how to implement calendar as your shared link do?

Comment: Hi @Rena, I only have the idea how to implement it and how it's supposed to work but for sure I'm not 100% sure exactly how to do it.